# JavaEE Application archiving

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ear

I have an application which consists of many modules. 
Though application is already developed in which each module is deployed as separate `ear`,`war` or `jar` depending on the functionality they provide. 
Today while discussing with one of my peer, there was one question suddenly came up which was
**Should we package all modules into one application archive trying to minimize number of archives ?**

**Or it is a better practice to keep archives separate according to their functionality ?**

Why I think of preferring first approach is that when product is given to client there must be only one archive rather than multiples for client's convenience.

Why I think of second approach is that I can maintain modularity. In case of any type of problem specific to one module, rest modules will keep servicing the clients as earlier.

For e.g. There is one module that does processing on files and sends acknowledgement files. There is another which after reading such acknowledgement files does something else. So in case second goes down, first will keep doing its work ?

**So please suggest me which one is better over other** with pros and cons of both these strategies.

Comment: do micro services, not monoliths